# Drupal's hook_nodeapi matches operation 'update' before operation 'insert' when adding a new node

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-node-hook

I'm working on a module, that make changes on nodes when adding new node, or when editing an existing nodes,

but I have found that when **adding a new node** the hook_nodeapi's operation matches ***case "update" and case "insert"***, when it is assumed to match **only** case "insert"

Is there any way to do it the right way, or differentiate between the "update" case and "insert" case ?

I'm using Drupal 6

Comment: Are you calling `node_save()` in your `insert` hook by any chance?

Comment: Have you verified that the 'update' case is invoked for the same node as the 'insert' one? Also, can you show us the code of your `hook_nodeapi()` implementation and the functions invoked from there?

Comment: Oh, and BTW: Be aware that both cases, 'insert' as well as 'update' are invoked _after_ the new or updated node has been saved. This is a common trap, as it is a bit counter intuitive. If you want to make changes _before_ the node gets saved, check out the 'presave' case, as this is invoked before.

Comment: Thanks guys, I made the code more general for the use in case "insert" and "update", and just used the "update", since it is called when adding nodes, and when editing nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the problem, here is the hook_nodeapi from drupal.org

```
<?php
function hook_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'presave':
      if ($node->nid && $node->moderate) {
        // Reset votes when node is updated:
        $node->score = 0;
        $node->users = '';
        $node->votes = 0;
      }
      break;
    case 'insert':
    case 'update':
      if ($node->moderate && user_access('access submission queue')) {
        drupal_set_message(t('The post is queued for approval'));
      }
      elseif ($node->moderate) {
        drupal_set_message(t('The post is queued for approval. The editors will decide whether it should be published.'));
      }
      break;
    case 'view':
      $node->content['my_additional_field'] = array(
        '#value' => theme('mymodule_my_additional_field', $additional_field), 
        '#weight' => 10,
      );
      break;
  }
}
?>
```

so for case insert and case update are called together

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $node->type to distinguis when you want to act.
Now you are acting on every node of your site.

```
if ($node->type == 'the_content_type_I_want') {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'presave':
      break;
    case 'insert':
      break;
    case 'update':
      break;
    case 'view':
      break;
  }
}
```